# $location.path in function is altering scope object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
$scope.copyOrder = function() {
        console.log($scope.products);
        CopyOrder.copying = true;
        CopyOrder.orderInfo = $scope.orderInfo;
        CopyOrder.products = $scope.products;
        console.log(CopyOrder.products);
        $location.path('/newOrder');
    };
```

When logging `$scope.products` shows that `$scope.products[0].imprint` is an empty array when it is not. If you take out `$location.path` the array inside the object shows that it has one object in it.

Essentially, with `$location.path` it shows this in the log:

```
$scope.products[0].imprint[0] (its length)
```

Without `$location.path`:

```
$scope.products[0].imprint[1]
```

I am copying two large objects from one controller (editing) to another (new).

EDIT: more code, and less code

```
$scope.copyOrder = function() {
        console.log($scope.products);
        $location.path('/newOrder');
    };
```

This still returns `$scope.products[0].imprint` as an empty array when it should have an array with one object.

```
$scope.copyOrder = function() {
    console.log($scope.products); // shows $scope.products[0].imprint as empty
    console.log($scope.products[0].imprint[0]); // shows an object in an array
    console.log(typeof $scope.products[0].imprint); // returns object and not array
    $location.path('/newOrder');
}
```

Comment: browsers have varied ways of drilling down on the value of an object. Try logging `JSON.stringify(CopyOrder.products)` to see its value at the time of logging.

Comment: I guess I could do that, then I'd have to parse it when bringing it back to another controller. I also still don't see why just having the $location.path in the function would alter that object.

Comment: Show the code for the controller when the path changes to `/newOrder`. Sounds like when the path changes, there is some logic in the controller or possibly on a route change event that sets `products` to an empty array.

Comment: My guess is you're looking at 2 separate scopes (each controller has its own) and when you log `$scope.products` after changing the path to `'/newOrder'` it's not yet initialized with the data from `CopyOrder.products`.

Comment: @user2341963 Its logged before the logic on the new controller, and it does not set the array to empty because it's taking that copied array and pushing it into a new one.

Comment: @HankScorpio The log happens before the change to /newOrder and it's scope. Even putting a timeout on the path change doesn't change the result.

Comment: Are you aware that when the path changes, whatever controller you're using gets re-initialized and all scope variables of the controller are cleared?

Comment: @user2341963 I assumed that, but it shouldn't happen before the path changes. Everything inside that object is correct except this array. The presence of $location.path even on a timeout shouldn't be affecting it even in the current scope.

Comment: I think you should post more code. Otherwise we're just stabbing in the dark. There's nothing obviously wrong with what you've posted, but you're only showing us 1 function from 1 of the controllers and you mention logging that isn't present in this code example. The order of things matters but without your code we can't spot the bug.

Comment: @HankScorpio I'm sorry, but I don't need to show more code and more importantly, I'm not allowed to. This function could be a console log and a path change and it would still be a problem. The presence of the path change changes the object.

Comment: I'm not telling you what you need to do, just what I (and one other developer who has commented here) need to help you with this. This isn't enough. Good luck.

Comment: @HankScorpio It's a 1000 line controller with a lot of DOM and data manipulation, copying, grouping, etc. I could give you a simpler function with only a console.log and a path change and it would still be a problem. It's a function, at the moment, that console logs an object and changes it's path.